# (Signed) measures defined on algebra instead of sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

So some authors consider (sigma additive) signed measures on algebras (that are closed only under finite unions) instead of on sigma algebras. This happens for instance when considering the subset of finitely additive signed measures that are sigma additive.

So my questions is what can I do with these a sigma additive measure on an algebra? I.e., do the usual convergence theorems hold? What kind of restrictions arise?

Comment: It would be useful to give examples.

Comment: in a book, i am not sure which it was, I have read that ca(A) is the subspace of ba(A), when the measure is not just finitely additive but also sigma additive. A is a field, not a sigma field. So they defined ca(A) w.r.t to a field even though the measures are sigma additive